# Error: "Index '' does not exist on table" when trying to create entities in Doctrine 2.0 CLI

Tags: doctrine-orm, entities

I have a mySQL database. I am trying to get Doctrine2 to create entities from the MySQL schema. I tried this with our production database, and got the following error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException] Index '' does not exist on table user

I then created a simple test database with only one table, and only three fields: an auto-increment primary key field and three varchar fields. When attempting to have doctrine create entities from this database, I got the same error.

Here is the table that I was trying to create an entitie for. (Should have been simple)

```
mysql> desc user;  
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| iduser    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| firstname | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |  
| lastname  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |  
| username  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |  
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the command that I used in an attempt to get said entities created:

```
./doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database test ../models/test
```

I am running:

- 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 (Ubuntu)
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.1
- Doctrine 2.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing the same problem right now. I have traced the problem back to the primary key being not identified / set correctly. The default value is boolean(false) which is cast to the string ''. Doctrine subsequently fails to locate an index for this attribute. ;-)

Solution: Define a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Yes, I traced the issue down to this. It seems that some of the tables in our database were created with fields that are "Unique auto-increment integers",mostly called 'id', rather than Primary Keys. We have been treating these fields as Primary Keys, and using them as such. However, they are not actually PK's.  I did not create our database. There are a number of 'quirks' in our structure, and this is one of them.  I created a program to find tables that do not have primary keys, and run MySQL ALTER TABLE scripts to change the 'id' index to a PK.

Comment: So, here is the process: (1) Make sure that all of your tables have primary keys, even if you have to add bogus primary keys temporarily. (2) Have Doctrine generate YAMLs from the schema. (3) Go through the YAMLs, and remove the bogus primary keys that you added. (4) Have Doctrine generate entities from the cleaned-up YAMLs.